# How to remove duplicate records from the table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, hive

I have a table with the following columns

```
NAME      FRIEND
----------------------
Apple     Flavour
Flavour   Apple
New       Banana
Banana    Flavour
```

I want to remove the columns having records with same combination for example
apple, flavour and flavour, apple are same. I want only one record among the two records when we have such combinations repeated.

Comment: Oracle and MySQL are two different products, with somewhat different versions of SQL. Which of them are you using?

Comment: Have you searched this site? This question has a lot of duplicates.

Comment: aer you actually trying to delete the rows that are duplicate or just want a query that selects only the non duplicates?

Comment: @jarlh i am trying this in Oracle and MySql

Comment: @JeremyC. I am trying to select only the non duplicates

Comment: @dataEnthusiast then Lalit Kumar's answer is what you need for mysql

Comment: @JeremyC. how do i use the same in Oracle

Comment: @dataEnthusiast it works in both oracle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca7174/1 aswell as mysql: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca717/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **LEAST** and **GREATEST** functions to fetch the unique combination.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'apple' a,   'flavour' b FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'flavour',   'apple' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'new',   'flavour' FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'banana',   'fruit' FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT least(a,b) a,
  8    greatest(a,b) b
  9  FROM data
 10  GROUP BY least(a,b),
 11    greatest(a,b)
 12  /

A       B
------- -------
banana  fruit
apple   flavour
flavour new

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates, start with select all rows where name < friend. Otherwise, also return if the reversed name/friend pair doesn't exist.

```
select *
from tablename t1
where t1.name < t1.friend
   or not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.name = t2.friend
                    and t1.friend = t2.name)
```

Alternatively, `select distinct`, using `greatest` and `least`:

```
select distinct least(name, friend), greatest(name, friend)
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ecdd/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test ( name, friend ) AS
          SELECT 'Apple', 'Flavour' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Flavour', 'Apple' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'New', 'Banana' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Banana', 'Flavour' FROM DUAL
/

DELETE FROM TEST
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT MIN( ROWID )
  FROM   test
  GROUP BY
  least( name, friend ),
  greatest( name, friend )
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 )
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ecdd/1/0)**:

```
|    NAME |  FRIEND |
|---------|---------|
| Flavour |   Apple |
|     New |  Banana |
|  Banana | Flavour |
```

---

Not quite as efficient with MySQL:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2466b/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  name VARCHAR(10),
  friend VARCHAR(10)
)
/

INSERT INTO Test
          SELECT 'Apple', 'Flavour' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Flavour', 'Apple' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'New', 'Banana' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Banana', 'Flavour' FROM DUAL
/

DELETE t1
FROM
  TEST t1
  INNER JOIN
  TEST t2
  ON ( t1.Name = t2.friend AND t1.friend = t2.name )
WHERE
  t1.Name > t1.friend
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2466b/1/0)**:

```
|   name |  friend |
|--------|---------|
|  Apple | Flavour |
|    New |  Banana |
| Banana | Flavour |
```